# Read And then HTML page +IOS

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

I want to read html page and wanna edit that HTML page.
example:-

There is `Textfield=Username`

i had inputed the value of `textfield=XYZ`

Now i want to that some webpage will open in the application and that webpage consist some textfield.

Now i want to read that webpage and search the textfield name username from that webform.
and fill that textfield with the value give in the textfield of the application.

I know that by using webview we can read and HTML page.
But is it feasible to search the particular word in the HTML page and make some edition in that.

To read HTML:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@\"http://www.apple.com\"]]];
```

But to search the perticular word and edit the textfield

IS it feasible? IF yes then how?

Comment: Look at your question description!! you are professional, so edit it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIWebVIew has 2 method can make it possible :

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

You can run a js in the webview to find your text and edit.

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

You can download the webpage then add some html string in it to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.But how do i read the webpage? Becoz without reading the webpage i m not able to search for the string by useing javascript.

Comment: Yes i want to read the HTML file and then wanna to search that whether the Textfield is there or not.If the page had a textfield than when i wannt to fill that textfield.

Comment: Reading html file is a basic ios url request. You may google it find some resources...      key word like : NSURLConnection